# Printing labels from Citrix

Tags: .net, printing, citrix

I am printing to a label printer that has the default label size set to 4 x 6 inches.  I loaded it up with 4 x 2 in labels then used this code to print to it:

```
Private Sub SetPaperSize(ByVal width As Double, ByVal height As Double)
    Dim size As New Drawing.Printing.PaperSize
    size.PaperName = "Custom Size"
    size.Width = width * 100
    size.Height = height * 100

    printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = size
    printDoc.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = size
End Sub
```

I run this code from my local machine and the printing comes out correctly.  I then print it from an application running on a citrix server and the printer still thinks that it is printing 4 x 6 in labels.  So I get my printed label followed by 2 blank labels.

Is there any way to force the local printer to use the settings I set on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read a comment in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707544/printing-on-citrix-server) which lead me down the right path.  I installed my label printer drivers on our citrix server, created a printer to test that it worked, and then hid that printer from end-users so they wouldn't accidentally print to it.

Everything is now printing correctly.